# How to convert string with pipes | | into dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a string with many pipes I want to convert them into dictionary `[String:Any]` how can I do that ?

Example

```
let input = "boolFirst=false|onProject=Active|passed=false"

Into -->

let output = [String: Any] = [boolFirst: false, onProject: "Active", passed: false]
```

so far tried with `components(separatedBy: "|")` & `components(separatedBy: "=")`
Is there any cleaner way to achieve ?

Comment: You have to first use `components(separatedBy:"|")` and then use `components(separatedBy:"=")` on each of those componenta

Comment: @Paulw11 Request you to post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```swift
let input = "boolFirst=false|onProject=Active|passed=false"

var output: [String: Any] = [:]

let pairs = input.components(separatedBy: "|")
for pair in pairs {
    let components = pair.components(separatedBy: "=")
    let key = components[0]
    
    if components[1] == "true" {
        output[key] = true
    } else if components[1] == "false" {
        output[key] = false
    } else {
        output[key] = components[1]
    }
}

print(output)
```

Output:

> ["onProject": "Active", "passed": false, "boolFirst": false]

Answer (score 1):

We can use the swift Regex and RegexBuilder functionality for this.

The regex would be

```
let regex = Regex {
        Capture {
            OneOrMore(.word)
        } transform: { substring in
            String(substring)
        }
        "="
        Capture  {
            OneOrMore(.any)
        }
    Optionally {
        "|"
    }
}
```

and then convert the result of matching the regex to a dictionary by using `reduce(into:)`

```
let output = input.matches(of: regex)
    .reduce(into: [String:Any]()) { $0[$1.output.1] = $1.output.2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string you are trying to parse is very similar to a URL query string. The key difference being the use of the `|` separator instead of `&`.

`URLComponents` has built in support for parsing a URL query string into individual `URLQueryItem` instances (which is basically name/value pairs).

As an alternate to using `components(separatedBy:)` to split up the string, the following code shows how to use `URLComponents`. It also uses a `switch` instead of `if/else` to handle the true/false values.

```swift
let input = "boolFirst=false|onProject=Active|passed=false"

var output = [String: Any]()

let urlcomps = URLComponents(string: "?" + input.replacingOccurrences(of: "|", with: "&"))
for item in urlcomps?.queryItems ?? [] {
    let key = item.name
    switch item.value {
        case "true":
            output[key] = true
        case "false":
            output[key] = false
        default:
            output[key] = item.value
    }
}

print(output)
```

Note that this implementation allows you to have values that contain a `|` or an `=` by encoding those values as `%7C` and `%3D` respectively. For example:

```
let input = "name=x%7Cy|other=x%3Dy"
```

This will result in `"name": "x|y"` and `"other": "x=y"` in the output.

Also, if you need an `&` in one of your values, you need to encode it as `%26`.